# Tests returning null, cant call right method

Tags: java, junit

I have this in my servlet:

```
@Override
public void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String responseText;
    try {
        String base = request.getParameter("base");
        String convertTo = request.getParameter("convertTo");
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("amount"));
        responseText = currencyRatesCalculation.getConvertedAmount(base, convertTo, amount);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON);
    } 
    catch (NullPointerException | NumberFormatException exception) {
        LOG.error("{} : Exception when parsing request parameters : ", LOG_STRING, exception);
        responseText = "Error when parsing request parameters";
    }
    response.getWriter().write(responseText);
}
```

This is how I'm trying to test it:

```
  @Mock
private MockSlingHttpServletRequest req;

@Mock
private MockSlingHttpServletResponse res;

@InjectMocks
private CurrencyExchangeServlet underTest;

@Before
public void setup() {
    underTest = new CurrencyExchangeServlet();
    req = context.request();
    res = context.response();
}

@Test
public void doGet_shouldReturnHeaderAsExpected() throws IOException {
    underTest.doGet(req, res);
    assertEquals(req.getContentType(), "application/json");
}
```

---

```
junitx.framework.ComparisonFailure:  
Expected :null
Actual   :application/json
```

Some advice? Where is mistake? Im watching on tutorials but cant find excatly some example for this what I have

Comment: req.getContentType() seems to return null

Comment: In your code, you're setting the content type on the response. In your test, you're checking the content type on the request.

Comment: its same when I try `res.getContentType()`

Comment: You're also not setting any parameters on your mock request. Is your catch block not invoked? It should, because `parseDouble()` will throw an exception.

Comment: No its not, im just getting null

Comment: Btw you should keep the right order for "expected" and "actual" like `assertEquals("application/json", res.getContentType());`.